# Counter Increment Exponentially

Tags: javascript, jquery, meteor

I'm trying to increment my counter every time but when the html is clicked the counter grows exponentially like +1, +2, +3, +4.

[image: Gif of it happening]

```
$('.dates').click(function(){
       $('#output').html(function(i, val) { return val*1+1 });
});
```

HTML:

```
<div id="output">0</div>
```

Heart Animation Code:

```
var rand = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100 + 1);
    var flows = ["flowOne", "flowTwo", "flowThree"];
    var colors = ["colOne", "colTwo", "colThree", "colFour", "colFive", "colSix"];
    var timing = (Math.random() * (1.3 - 0.3) + 1.6).toFixed(1);
    // Animate Particle
    $('<div class="particle part-' + rand + ' ' + colors[Math.floor(Math.random() * 6)] + '" style="font-size:' + Math.floor(Math.random() * (30 - 22) + 22) + 'px;"><i class="fa fa-heart-o"></i><i class="fa fa-heart"></i></div>').appendTo('.particle-box').css({ animation: "" + flows[Math.floor(Math.random() * 3)] + " " + timing + "s linear" });
    $('.part-' + rand).show();
    // Remove Particle
    setTimeout(function () {
      $('.part-' + rand).remove();
    }, timing * 1000 - 100);
```

1. Why is it incrementing exponentially?
2. How do I make it increment by 1 every time? Like 0, 1, 2, 3, 4

Comment: Can you reproduce this on JSFiddle?

Comment: It works well https://jsfiddle.net/v58dfs8u/ I think you bind your event multiple times

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May be it is considering it as string. Use `parseInt` to parse the value as an integer instead of using String Concatenation:

```
$('.dates').click(function() {
  $('#output').html(function(i, val) {
    return parseInt(val, 10) + 1;
  });
});
```

Working snippet:

```js
$('.dates').click(function() {
  $('#output').html(function(i, val) {
    return parseInt(val, 10) + 1;
  });
  return false;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#" class="dates">Click</a>
<div id="output">0</div>
```

Comment: `val*1` will cast val into a number anyway, so this is not the problem. However using `parseInt` is more explicit indeed.

Comment: The working snippet somehow blocks the heart animation code below it

Comment: @user3421197 Unless you post the full code, how on earth would you expect us to understand and solve your issue?

Comment: @user3421197 Can you please go to [JSBin](http://jsbin.com) and recreate what you have? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Most likely, you are registering a new click event listener every time you click.

Please check and post the code that surrounds the line `$('.dates').click(...)`.

Make sure this line is called only once in your code, and not again later.